# My trigger doesnt work due to a problem related to the clause then

Tags: sql, triggers

So i have a project where i have to build a database and establish connections between the tables and to create some views, procedures and triggers.
So i created one and i can´t seem to why it doesn´t work.
Here is the piece of code of the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_ValidarEstoque
ON Trabalho.Equipamento
FOR INSERT 
AS
 BEGIN
    DECLARE @estoque_minimo INT;

-- Defina o valor do estoque mínimo aceitável
SET @estoque_minimo = 10;

-- Verifique se o estoque está abaixo do limite mínimo, se estiver aparece uma mensagem
IF NEW.Stock < @estoque_minimo THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Estoque abaixo do limite mínimo';
END IF;
END;
```

And here's the table i m using if it helps:

```
CREATE TABLE Trabalho.Equipamento (
Equipamento_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Designacao VARCHAR(99),
DataAquisicao DATE,
Stock INT,
Fornecedor_ID INT,
Colaborador_ID INT,
FOREIGN KEY (Colaborador_ID) REFERENCES 
Trabalho.Colaborador(Colaborador_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(Fornecedor_ID) REFERENCES 
Trabalho.Fornecedor(Fornecedor_ID)
);
```

I tried removing some pieces of the code and when i thought it would be working a new error would appear. I get the following error if it helps.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure TRG_ValidarEstoque, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 221]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.

Thank you

Comment: please specify database you use. Triggers are highly vendor-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is SQL Server from the error message, there is no then or end if, the syntax is just IF (condition) (statement) ELSE (statement)

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL Server, remove 'THEN' - T-SQL automatically assumes the next statement after the 'IF' is what you want to execute if the 'IF' condition evaluates as true.

Comment: Now i get a new error, yay.  Related to the Signal sqlstate

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_ValidarEstoque
ON Trabalho.Equipamento
FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @estoque_minimo INT;

    -- Defina o valor do estoque mínimo aceitável
    SET @estoque_minimo = 10;

    -- Verifique se o estoque está abaixo do limite mínimo, se estiver aparece uma mensagem
    IF (SELECT Stock FROM inserted) < @estoque_minimo
    BEGIN
        THROW 50000, 'Estoque abaixo do limite mínimo', 1;
    END;
END;
```